# Permutation of words in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticsearch I would like to treat documents as identical in the case where the values of a specific text field only differ by the order of the terms.

How can I accomplish that in elasticsearch?

Update, with a more detailed formulation of the goal:

- Given I have five documents with the phrases 1) "iphone white", 2) "white iphone", 3) "white iphones", 4) "black iphone" and 5) "white android" (where the first three phrases consist of the two basic terms "white" and "iphone")
- When I search for "iphone",
- Then I would like only two results, for example "iphone white" and "black iphone" (such that I avoid duplications due to permutations of words).
- The result that I want for each distinct combination of basic terms is the distinct phrase that has the highest score in elasticsearch for that query. In this example there are two distinct combinations of basic terms that matches the query: A) "iphone"+"white" and B) "iphone"+"black". For A phrases 1,2,3 match and for B phrase 4 matches. Phrase 1 could be the phrase with the highest score...

Comment: I don't understand "avoid duplications due to permutations of words". What duplications and what permutations are you afraid of?

Comment: Dont understand the requirement too. Do you mean the position of search term in documents ?

Comment: I want one result "iphone white". and not two results "iphone white" and "white iphone", since the difference is only a different order of words. I tried terms aggregation on a raw subfield but that returned both phrases.

Comment: :-) that's not possible. You are searching for a single word "iphone". Of course both documents will match. You need to come up with another rule to define which document match and which don't.

Comment: Good point, I will update the question.